# Is there a way of making both bar chart and graph chart in one image by using JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

I have searched many docs in google but didn't find anything about creating bar chart and graph chart in one image by using JFreeChart. Does anybody know it?

Answer (score 1):

[`OverlaidBarChartDemo`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartOverlaidBarChartDemo.htm) is one such example, but you should also browse the [JFreeChart Demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp).